# 'PK_dbo.EntityName' is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint.EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 6 code first. I have three Entity like these :

```
public class Doctor
{
    public string DoctorID { get; set; } 
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
 }

public class ExpertiseDetails
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public short expertiseID { get; set; }
    [Key , Column(Order = 2)]
    public string DoctorID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("expertiseID")]
    public Expertise expertise { get; set; }
    public Doctor doctor { get; set; }
}


public class Expertise
{
    [Key]
    public short expertiseID { get; set; }
    public string expertiseTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I need a `one to many` realationship between `Expertise` and `Doctor`,When I run update-database statement in console `nuGet` this error shows :

```
'PK_dbo.ExpertiseDetails' is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: i think you have data in your db, please drop data and try again

Comment: @Moein . I try your suggestion but it doesn't work !

Answer (score 3):

Having experienced a similar issue after renaming the table schema, I solved by explicitly delete the PK name with sql.

In my case the issue arose when a primary key was changed in a table after renaming the table schema:

Original:

- dbo.LogEntries with PK-name: PK_dbo.LogEntries

step 1: schema change:

- Logging.LogEntries with PK unchanged

step 2: PK change

- PK changed: results in `DropPrimaryKey("Logging.LogEntries");`

This last line translates to the PK-name: `PK_Logging.LogEntries` which doesn't exists.

**The fix**:
In general there are several way's to fix this. I dropped the PK through a sql-statement in the explicit migration.

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE [Logging].[LogEntries] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.LogEntries]");
```

Be advised; I had full production access in case it would fail and didn't use migrations to roll-back to a previous state.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database#defaultcalculated-names-may-not-match-existing-schema) the default names may not match your database. In this case, the documentation says to manually modify your migration file (`Up` and `Down` methods) to make use of the `name` parameter, which will override the default name of the primary or foreign key (or other database object depending on the situation).

For example, for me, the generated line:

```cs
DropPrimaryKey("dbo.MyTable");
```

becomes:

```cs
DropPrimaryKey("dbo.MyTable", "PK_MyTable");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the primary key to the name the entity framework asking about.

For example, if an error message mentioned `'PK_dbo.TableName'` and the existing primary key does not have `'dbo.'`, add `'dbo.'` to it's name and run the application or update the database with `nuget` package manager console.

Comment: But what if a previous migration added it by its old name?